# Google App Maker - Reference multiple tables from External MySql Database

Tags: mysql, database, model, datasource, google-app-maker

I recently began using Google App Maker and in order to reference multiple tables from an external MySql Database, do I have to create multiple **Data Models** for each table or do I have to create multiple **datasources** inside one **Data Model** and adding all the fields in it? The database has 15 tables in total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create model per table.

You can connect your existing database to App Maker (in application settings) and import tables as models (create model -> existing model). So you don't need to re-create fields.

Please be aware that as you change models in App Maker the database from application settings changes accordingly. So I would recommend use prototype database in application settings and production one in production deployment.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help.